# Determining current user in views (using custom user fields)

Tags: django

Basically, I want to know if there is a substitute for `request.user` when using custom users in Django.

I have the following in my posts/models.py file:

```
class Post(models.Model):
     text = models.TextField()
     user_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='posts')

class EduUser(AbstractUser):
    # additional field
```

In my settings file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'posts.EduUser'
```

In my views file:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    Post.objects.create(text = request.POST['post_content'],
                        user_id = request.user
                        )
```

---

Of course, this is returning an error saying
`"Post.user_id" must be a "EduUser" instance.`
Any ideas of what is needed in replace of `request.user`? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In fact, that should work. Did you restart your webserver?

Comment: Is your `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` set correctly ?

Comment: Hmmm I think it might be that I'm trying to post without logging in as a User (unfortunately I disabled my login feature) The full error is:
`Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x10dabd950>>": "Post.user_id" must be a "EduUser" instance.`

Comment: Yes, you need to login.

Comment: :facepalm: Yep, just added back my login feature and it worked. Thanks for the help guys, I really appreciate it.